# Show that don't exists smooth extensions

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

> Find $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ smooth such that don't exists $U$ open neighborhood of $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $F|_{X}=f$

First I think in a set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for example the union to $[0,1]$ in $X$ axis and $[0,1]$ in $Y$ axis, but I don't sure to these is the right way I have many problems in the part to find the function $f$ and why don't exists $F:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $F|_{X}=f$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: try this first when $n=1$, and make sure that your choice of $X$ is *not* a closed set. You should quickly be able to come up with a function $f$ that works from there by thinking back to first year/high school calculus.